# Theme does not respect spaces between paragraphs in pages

Tags: posts, pages, formatting

I am working with a theme that focuses on special types of posts.  It seems that the author has neglected pages and as a result, paragraph spacing in pages is not respected.  The next paragraph simply appears on the next line instead of leaving a line of space between paragraphs.  This does not affect special posts, but it does affect pages.

What is the best way to fix that?

Comment: It may just be a CSS style that needs to be fixed. Have you got a link I can see?

Comment: Here you go: http://www.2035themes.com/muusico/  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The theme's style sheet uses the reset method to set all margins on the `<p>` tag (and many others) to 0 (this is common practice). So you would need to add a style declaration into your style sheet to add the top and bottom margin back in for the `<p>` tag.

For example: you could add this to your style sheet after the reset.

```
p {
 margin: 10px 0;
}
```

This will add a top and bottom margin of 10px. You can change this to whatever value you like.

You could also set the margins individually.

```
p {
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-right: 0;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-left: 0;
}
.added p {
  margin: 0;
}
```

**Edit:**
Included extra css to fix "Added by"

Comment: But wouldn't this affect custom posts, which already have correct paragraph spacing?  20 extra pixels between paragraphs on top of what's already on those pages would be an overkill.

Comment: No because there is no margin on the `<p>` tags in the custom posts either. There are just extra, empty, paragraphs after each paragraph.

Comment: @RandyS you can accept the answer. Just check for the arrow below the up and down arrows. Click on the arrow, it will go green. This will mean the question is solved by this specific answer. You also gain 2 reputation points which is the key to unlocking more site features for you :-)